# How to modify default ansible reachable test method

Tags: ansible

As we know, ansible connects remote machine by ssh, then ansible will run setup task, in this task, there is a step which will create a temp directory under $HOME/.ansible/tmp folder (default setting is under $HOME/.ansible/tmp, we could modify this in ansible.cfg file).

If failed to create the temp folder, ansible will report ansible authentication or permission failure, the remote host is unreachable.

However, I have a problem, my remote machine is accessed by serial console over LAN, it cannot create temp folder, can I modify the default reachable test method?

Or does anyone please give me suggestion how to manage remote host in ansible through serial console over LAN.

thanks.

Comment: If ansible can't even create the temp directory, then it will hard for it do any meaningful tasks on the machine. Can you who us an example of how your inventory is set up to use serial console over LAN?

Comment: @SztupY, thank you for your reminding.  Yes, I know this will have a lot of restricts to ansible's power, I just want to run some basic commands, such as set hostname, set business IP address, after this, I can access by normal ansible method.

Comment: @SztupY, in my mind,  I want to use expect module to test the serial console be logged on or not, if it has been logged on, directly return, if not, login in configured console user and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to prepare your remote box to be managed by Ansible, there are two ways:

1) `raw` module if the box in question is accessible via ssh and is able to execute arbitrary commands. This method is used, for example, to install Python2 on Ubuntu 16 images to allow Ansible execute `setup` and other modules.

2) Use commands/script from your control machine first. For example if you use raw tcp connection to get your serial console connection, you can do something like this:

```
- hosts: box
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - expect:
        command: nc box 1234
        responses:
          login: user
          password: password
          user: /path/to/bootstrap_script.sh && exit
      delegate_to: localhost
    - setup:
    - other_ansible_module:
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try it later, I almost give up.